# ASP.NET MVC Beta 1 - where is Html.RenderPartial?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, renderpartial

I'm just in the process of upgrading my Preview 5 application to Beta 1, and I'm nearly there save for this one error when trying to render a control:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not
>   contain a definition for
>   'RenderPartial' and no extension
>   method 'RenderPartial' accepting a
>   first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

My markup (in the .aspx View Content Page) is:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Controls/UserForm", ViewData); %>
```

I've tried using Microsoft.Web.Mvc but to no avail.  Does anyone know where Html.RenderPartial has gone, or what alternative I could use?

Comment: They sure love moving stuff around  :)

Comment: Yeah, I think they get some kind of sick pleasure from it...

Comment: Great question - we're upgrading to 1.0 from Preview 5 today and this really helped!

Comment: Well, as annoying as it is, better they get it right during the Beta than have to change it after the RTM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And also don't forget to add namespaces like below to the web config, I think preview 5 default web.config does not have System.Web.Mvc.Html in it:

```
<namespaces>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
 <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
 <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
 <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
</namespaces>
```

Answer (score 9):

Now fixed - the conflict was a difference in Web.config requirements between Preview 5 and Beta 1.  The following needs to be added into the system.web compilation assemblies node:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

After this change, all of my old HtmlHelper methods magically came back!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding the assembly reference I also had to add the line

```
 <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>"
```

to the pages/namespaces section in web.config file.

Comment: In addition to this you need to ensure the compiler is set to 3.5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944015/problem-creating-my-own-extension-to-htmlhelper/944761#944761