# Strongly typed actionlink with asp.net mvc beta?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I used to be able to do the following in Preview 3

```
<%=Html.BuildUrlFromExpression<AController>(c => c.AnAction(par1, par2)%>
```

How am I supposed to create urls in a strongly typed way with the MVC Beta?
The only thing so far I have found is

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("aName", "ActionName", "ControllerName")%>
```

This is not strongly typed off course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the ASP.NET MVC Beta Futures, which is a separate download

[ASP.NET MVC Beta Futures](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18459)

then your original code will work as before.

See this post for getting it working:
[SO post on missing extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211493/aspnet-mvc-beta-1-where-is-htmlrenderpartial#211524)

Comment: Thanks. So if you didn't know that you had to download an extra part of it, there is no way of creating a type safe url?!
Also, how did you know that?

Comment: From the SO post I have added

Answer (score 3):

The [`Microsoft.Web.Mvc`](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18459) assembly provides extension methods to the `HtmlHelper` which allow something like

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<SomeController>(c => c.Index()) %>
```