# Problem creating my own extension to HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, extension-methods

I have an extension method to HtmlHelper:

```
<%= Html.MyMethod( params )%>
```

It works in visual studio, but throws (at runtime):

> Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'MyMethod'

The odd bit is that this does work:

```
<%= HtmlHelperExtensions.MyMethod( Html, params ) %>
```

Why does my method not work as an extension, but does as a normal static call?

Comment: What version of the framework are you using?  Could you also show the helper methods signature?

Comment: It's a simple method, something like: public static class HtmlHelperExtensions { public static string Localise( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string key, params string[] args ) ...

Comment: I think I'm on the latest patched up release version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer in the web.config - there's a section that tells it how to compile C# embedded in HTML:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" 
                  extension=".cs"
                  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

This is missing an extra flag that tells it to use the 3.5 compiler tricks that let extension methods and anonymous types work in the HTML:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" 
                  extension=".cs"
                  type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are importing the namespace containing the extension method in your view.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyProject.MyExtensions"%>
```

Or add it in your web.config so it will be available on every view:

```
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="MyProject.MyExtensions"/>
        </namespaces>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but not it. If that were the problem then the static call (HtmlHelperExtensions.MyMethod) wouldn't work either.